# How to automatically change a Django Model field after a specific amount of time?

Tags: django, timer, model, task, signals

I'm working on an e-commerce website that includes an auction process. For this I have created an Auction Model with different status options: (e.g.: active, closed, canceled, completed, etc.). I want to give users a fixed amount of time (say 5 hours) to partake in the auction and add their bids, after which the auction status will automatically be changed from "active" to say "completed" and the users won't be able to submit bids anymore and a winner will be determined.

What is the best way to achieve this in Django? I have read about using background tasks like django-backgound-tasks or Celery. But this would require me to run the task every minute or so to check if the 5 hours have passed or not.

The other things option I came across are using some type of timer or Django signals.

I'm not sure which would be the best strategy here and therefore am asking the community for its opinion, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [periodic_task](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) it provides more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ivan, but this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. Is asking in a periodic way really the best way to do this? Isn't there a way I could assign a type of timer to the task and have it automatically do something after 5 hours? Thanks again!